# C Convert Tree Struct to JSON

Tags: c, json, tree

Is there a resonably easy way to in C convert a **tree** struct such as the below to JSON? For easy read and write to files and store between executions?

Or in another format perhaps (I only choose JSON because I am more experienced with it).

```
struct node {
  datatype data; // whatever data is inside the node
  struct node *left_ptr; // may be NULL
  struct node *right_ptr; // may be NULL
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: serialize a null pointer as `null`, pick an appropriate representation for `data` (let's call that `data_repr`), then serialize a `node` as (pseudocode)

```
{ "left" : <serialize(left)>, "right" : <serialize(right)>, "data" : <data_repr>}
```

Comment: I'm sure I mentioned it was a tree 'convert a tree struct'

Comment: @PezCuckow: 'scuse me, missed that bit. Undid -1, apologies

Answer (score 0):

[Binary trees can be stored as arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). In other words, you can just store `datatype` elements one per line. Save and load the tree using [level order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Queue-based_level_order_traversal).